# Finding the number of occurences of each level of a factor in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, lapply

I have a dataframe that I split into a list of data frames by name. For the factor variable "Status" there are 3 levels: Scheduled, Canceled, Postponed. I would like to count the number of each level of Status for each name and I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I had tried using summary in lapply but couldn't get it to work. I also don't know if there's an easier way to do this without splitting the dataframe. I also would appreciate some advice as to how to provide a good sample of the list of dataframe for those who would like to provide an answer.

Comment: `table(your.data.frame$Status)`

Comment: that doesn't give me the total per person though

Comment: `table(your.data.frame$Status, your.data.frame$Name) `, edit your question and provide some data to illustrate your problem so that we can understand it and help you better.

Comment: I had asked how to provide a sample of data from a list of dataframes. Any input would be helpful @JilberUrbina

Answer (score 0):

You can use function  `table` and supply the column name having different levels as the parameter which should give you the counts for each level in that variable. Like below:

```
#### Iris Example
data(iris)

head(iris)


#### Column name Species have three levels:
#### setosa versicolor virginica
#### Below code counts each level in the iris dataset
table(iris$Species)
#setosa versicolor  virginica 
#50         50         50 

#### Let's split the data randomly
index<-sample(1:nrow(iris),nrow(iris) * .8, replace = FALSE)
dataset_1<-iris[index,]
dataset_2<-iris[-index,]


table(dataset_1$Species)
#setosa versicolor  virginica 
#42         34         44 

table(dataset_2$Species)
#setosa versicolor  virginica 
#8         16          6
```

Answer (score 0):

A tidy verse solution:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

#dummy data

df1 <- data.frame(name = factor(c('Dave', 'Bob', 'Ryan')), status = factor(c('a', 'b', 'c')), number = c(10, 20, 30))
df2 <- data.frame(name = factor(c('Dave', 'Bob', 'Ryan')), status = factor(c('b', 'a', 'c')), number = c(5, 23, 61))

#add a column to count factor levels

df1['num'] <- 1
df2['num'] <- 1
ldf <- list(df1, df2)


#solution

rbind.fill(ldf) %>% group_by(name, status) %>% summarise(total_status = sum(num))
```